# How to call grib_get_data -p programmatically with python3 in a docker container?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, flask, os.system, grib

Just wondering how to make DOCKER do the :

`os.system(f"grib_ls -P time {downloaded}")`

`os.system(f"grib_get_data -p dataDate,dataTime {downloaded} > {csvPath}")`

... **programatically** without calling the os.system ?

Any ideas ?

Comment: What do these commands do?  How would Docker potentially be involved?  Do you already have a Docker image with the software you need?

Comment: Yes - docker is completed. What I'm presenting here is a small part of a Flask app which is responsible for requesting weather data from Copernicus CDSAPI - this data is than saved as a *.grib file and eventually it's converted to a *.JSON